# JQuery/Javascript invalid argument script error on window resize in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, resize, invalid-argument

I'm getting a script error in IE8 when using the following snippet for reacting on window resize event, although the browser executes the function 'dummyFunc()' as intended:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
var resizeTimer;
  jq(window).resize(function() {
      clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
      //resizeTimer = setTimeout(reloadSlider(), 100, 'JavaScript');
      resizeTimer = setTimeout(dummyFunc(), 100, 'JavaScript');
  });

function dummyFunc() {
    alert('hurra');
}
```

So, the problem is not that the browser does not alert, the problem is rather that there is a "script error" message displayed in Internet Explorer, which is unlovely. I'd appreciate any hints on how to get rid of the error message.

Thank you

Comment: As a side note, the third parameter is not supported in IE. have a look here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout - "Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer. If you want to enable this functionality on that browser you must use a compatibility code"

Answer (score 2):

Change `dummyFunc()` to `dummyFunc`. As you have it, you are executing the function immediately, and then passing `undefined` (the result of the function call) to `setTimeout`.

You want to instead pass a reference to the function:

```
resizeTimer = setTimeout(dummyFunc, 100, 'JavaScript');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run ie8 while debugging the script.  Press F12 while viewing the page and start debugging from there.  Then you'll have to analyze the point where you get the script error.

Answer (score 0):

resizeTimer is undefined until the first setTimeout. Try `if(resizeTimer) { clearTimeout(resizeTimer); ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `dummyFunc` immediately by calling it. `dummyFunc()` gets replaced by the return value of the function, which is undefined.

```
resizeTimer = setTimeout(dummyFunc(), 100, 'JavaScript');
```

Just omit the bracers at `dummyFunc` to pass it as a reference.

```
resizeTimer = setTimeout(dummyFunc, 100);
```

**I've never seen the last parameter you passed, so I left it out. This could very easily be throwing errors in IE8.**